# Extracting element contents with XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a simple XML file with which I need to produce a document from using XSL.

The basis of the XML file is:

```
<badges>
   <badge id="s1">
   <name>Climbing</name>
   <description>This badge is awarded to scouts who have shown a proficiency in climbing</description>
      <levels>
         <availability level="beaver">Not Available</availability>
         <availability level="cub">Available</availability>
         <availability level="scout">Available</availability>
      </levels>
  </badge>
</badges>
```

I'm trying to produce a document which displays the availability of the activitities to the different levels of scouts.

So for example I want something which looks like:

```
Climbing..
Beaver: Not available
Cub: Available
Scout: Available
```

The XSL I have created is below, the problem is with iterating over the availability elements.

```
<xsl:for-each select="badges/badge">
                    <!-- Sort ascending by name and print them out to the screen -->
                    <xsl:sort select="name" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
                    <!-- check if it's an activity badge :) -->
                    <!-- Test value of badge, if activity then print to screen -->
                    <xsl:if test="@type='activity'">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="color: #3b5598; font-family:'Open Sans',sans-serif;">
                                <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
                                <br/>
                                <xsl:value-of select="description"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <xsl:for-each select="badges/badge/levels">
                            <!-- Test value of badge, if activity then print to screen -->
                            <xsl:for-each select="availability">

                                <!-- Check the attirbute and then check the content of the element 

                                <xsl:if test="@level='beaver'">

                                    ho

                                </xsl:if>

                                <xsl:if test="@level='scout'">

                                    ho

                                </xsl:if>

                                <xsl:if test="@level='cub'">

                                    ho

                                </xsl:if>-->

                                Hi

                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
```

If anyone has any ideas or suggestions I'd love to hear them!

Thanks

Comment: You should better show us a sample html of the desired output

Answer (score 0):

The exact output you want to achieve is not quite clear. You could try something along the lines of:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Beaver</th>
        <th>Cub</th>
        <th>Scout</th>
    </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="badges/badge">
            <tr>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="description"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="levels/availability[@level='beaver']"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="levels/availability[@level='cub']"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="levels/availability[@level='scout']"/></td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>
```

which in your example would produce:

[image]

or:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <table border="1">
        <xsl:for-each select="badges/badge">
            <tr><th colspan="2"><xsl:value-of select="name"/></th></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="2"><xsl:value-of select="description"/></td></tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="levels/availability">
                <tr>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="@level"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>
```

to produce:

[image]